# "Permission denied" error while building AllJoyn framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to build Alljoyn framework for my iOS application. But when build this framework I'm getting ***can't exec '/usr/local/Cellar/scons' (Permission denied)*** error. I have done the following '***sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local***', but no luck!

Can you please help me on what the error could be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the complete path including the destination file.
I was getting a similar error because I was taking the file path as "/xxxx/alljoyn-15.04.00-osx_ios-sdk/alljoyn_objc/bin/".
The error vanished after updating the file path as : "/xxxx/alljoyn-15.04.00-osx_ios-sdk/alljoyn_objc/bin/AllJoynCodeGenerator"